# "Bad Request Exception" when trying to use AWS Transcribe using Python to transcribe a voice data sent as JSON dump using websocket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use AWS transcribe using Python. Please do not suggest boto.

Please do look into this and suggest me what I should do to fix the error.

The response I receive is:

> b'\x00\x00\x00\xa3\x00\x00\x00ah\x10k\xe1\x0f:exception-type\x07\x00\x13BadRequestException\r:content-type\x07\x00\x10application/json\r:message-type\x07\x00\texception{"Message":"Unexpected
>   WebSocket frame received."}\xbd\xceK\x8a'

This goes on till I terminate it myself.

The code to transcribe. Please fill in your AWS key and secret to replicate.

Thanks in advance.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac, urllib
import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy as np

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
text = ""
voice_data = {}

def createPresignedUrl(data):
    method = 'GET'
    service = 'transcribe'
    region = data['region']
    host = 'transcribestreaming.' + region + '.amazonaws.com:8443'
    endpoint = "wss://" + host

    def sign(key, msg):
        return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

    def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
        kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
        kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
        kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
        kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
        return kSigning

    access_key = data['key']
    secret_key = data['secret']
    if access_key == '' or secret_key == '':
        print('No access key is available.')
        sys.exit()

    # Create a date for headers and the credential string
    t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    amz_date = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ') # Format date as YYYYMMDD'T'HHMMSS'Z'
    datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

    canonical_uri = '/stream-transcription-websocket' 

    canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n'
    signed_headers = 'host'

    algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'

    canonical_querystring  = 'X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Credential=' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(access_key + '/' + credential_scope)
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Date=' + amz_date
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Expires=300'
    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers
    canonical_querystring += '&language-code=' + data['languageCode']
    canonical_querystring += '&media-encoding=pcm'
    canonical_querystring += '&sample-rate=' + str(data['sampleRate'])

    payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(('').encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    # Step 6: Combine elements to create canonical request
    canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash

    string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amz_date + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    # Create the signing key
    signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)

    # Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
    signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    canonical_querystring += '&X-Amz-Signature=' + signature

    request_url = endpoint + canonical_uri + "?" + canonical_querystring

    return request_url

data = {
    'key': '',
    'secret': '',
    'region': 'us-east-1',
    'languageCode': 'en-US',
    'sampleRate': 44100
}

url = createPresignedUrl(data)

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 4096

stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

def pcmEncode(in_data):
    offset = 0
    input_len = len(in_data)
    buffer = []

    for i in range(input_len):
        offset += 2
        s = max(-1, min(1, in_data[i]))
        b = (s * 32768) if (s < 0) else (s * 32767)
        buffer.insert(offset, b)

    return buffer

def downsampleBuffer(buffer, outputSampleRate = 16000) :
    if outputSampleRate == RATE :
        return buffer

    sampleRateRatio = RATE / outputSampleRate
    newLength = round( len(buffer) / sampleRateRatio )
    result = []
    offsetResult = 0
    offsetBuffer = 0

    while offsetResult < newLength :
        nextOffsetBuffer = round((offsetResult + 1) * sampleRateRatio)
        accum = 0
        count = 0

        len_buffer = nextOffsetBuffer if nextOffsetBuffer < len(buffer) else len(buffer)

        for i in range( offsetBuffer, len_buffer):
            accum += buffer[i]
            count += 1

        result.append(accum / count)
        offsetResult += 1
        offsetBuffer = nextOffsetBuffer

    return result

async def start_stream():
    try:
        connection = websockets.connect(url)        
        while True:
            voice_data = stream.read(CHUNK)

            async with connection as ws:
                sent_data = {
                    "headers": {
                        ":message-type": {"type": "string", "value": "event"}, 
                        ":event-type": {"type": "string", "value": "AudioEvent"},
                        ":content-type": {"type": "string", "value": "application/octet-stream"}
                    },
                    "body": str(voice_data)
                }
                await ws.send(json.dumps(sent_data))

                response = await ws.recv()

                print(response)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_stream())

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```